# Incorrect variable when calling callback in JS

Tags: javascript

I am getting the wrong filename in the following code. I'm sure its obvious what the mistake is but i dont see it. I get the correct amount of errors however all the filename are the same rather then the filename in error.

```
for(var i=0; i<this.files.length; ++i){
    var f = this.files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        if(e.total>maxFilesize){
            tooBigFilesLs.push(f.name);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Javascript Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

There is just an example about it in that article in "Creating closures in loops: A common mistake"

Try with this:

```
for(var i=0; i<this.files.length; ++i){
    var f = this.files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    (function(name){

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            if(e.total>maxFilesize){
                    tooBigFilesLs.push(name);
        }
    }
     }(f.name));
}
```

(not tested)

Basically, when you define that function on 'onload', you are creating a closure, and all the functions you create in that loop share it, so all the functions has access to 'f' and 'reader', so 'f' will remain pointing to the last file in the loop. Adding the anonymous closure in my example, using that 'name' parameter, you ensure that the function in the 'onload' gets the right name.

Comment: The reader outside of the func bothers me. Will that work? i end up writing `for(var i=0; i<this.files.length; ++i){ var f = this.files[i]; (function(f){...})(f);` before you pasted your code. That definitely does work. BTW your link explained it clearly

Comment: Well, I don't know what is that FileReader object, but probably is good idea to put it inside of the closure, as I understand you want to create one per file.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a **closure issue** with your for loop.

[Here](http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62) is an example of how to handle it.

```
// Basic idea...

reader.onload  = (function(value) {
    return function() {
        alert(value);
    }
})(f.name);
```

Comment: Actually, i dont pass the value into reader.onload. Or at least i dont know how to. The other answer clearly shows me the solution (i read the link before he pasted code)

Comment: I show you the basic solution which solves the problem. You just have to plug your logic in. Sorry I didn't do all the work for you.